# Blender Snapping problems

Tags: mesh, objects, snapping

[image][image]Does anyone know why The blender snapping is not working correctly for me? I'm trying to snap a cube onto another cubes edge and everytime It "snaps" it goes below it, Tilts it, etc. It never works how i was intending.

Comment: Can you include pictures of what is happening?

Comment: Just added them.

Comment: Try to use only "Vertex" without "Align Rotation to Target".